# Django form will not validate

Tags: python, html, django, forms, validation

I am working with Django forms and for some reason, this form will not validate! It submits alright, or at least the runserver shows an http post response with code 200 (ok). For some reason though, my form will not pass the is_valid test!

views.py:

```
def new_show(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    img_form = ImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
show_form = NewShowForm(request.POST)
if show_form.is_valid():
    new_Show = Show()
    new_Show.title=show_form.cleaned_data['title']
    new_Show.body=show_form.cleaned_data['body']
    new_Show.pub_date=timezone.now()
    new_Show.location=show_form.cleaned_data['location']
    new_Show.time=show_form.cleaned_data['time']
    new_Show.save()     
    if img_form.is_valid():
        image=Image(image=request.FILES['imageFile'])
        new_Show.image_set.add(image)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('shows'))

    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('shows'))
else:
    show_form = NewShowForm()
    img_form = ImageForm()
return render_to_response(
    'shows/new_show.html',
    {'show_form': show_form, 'img_form': img_form},
    context_instance=RequestContext(request)
    )
```

Here is my template snippet:

```
    <form action="{% url "new_show" %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p>{{ show_form.non_field_errors }}</p>
    <p>
        <label for="title">Title:</label>
        <input type="text" name="title"/>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="body">Body:</label>
        <textarea type="text" name="body"> </textarea>
    </p>

    <p>
        <label for="location">Location:</label>
        <input type="text" name="location"/>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="time">Date:</label>
        <input type="text" id="time" maxlength="25" size="25" name="time"><a href="javascript:NewCal('time','ddmmmyyyy',true,24)"><img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}../../static/cal.gif" width="16" height="16" border="0" alt="Pick a date"></a>

    </p>



<!-- Upload Form. Note enctype attribute! -->


    {% csrf_token %}
    <p>{{ img_form.non_field_errors }}</p>
    <p>{{ img_form.imageFile.label_tag }}</p>
    <p>
        {{ img_form.imageFile.errors }}
        {{ img_form.imageFile }}
    </p>

<p><input type="submit" value="Add Upcoming Show"></input></p>
</form>
```

Here is my form Class:

```
class NewShowForm(forms.Form):
    title=forms.CharField()
    body=forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextArea)
    location=forms.CharField()
    time=forms.DateTimeField(required=True)
class ImageForm(forms.Form):
    imageFile = forms.FileField(required=False, label='Select an Image')
```

Please help me!

Comment: Please a) try to fix your indentation and b) show your form class declarations.

Comment: ok I think I got the indents right. I added the forms.py

Comment: Based on just a quick look over the form code, two things leap out at me. One, fields are required by default - you have `required=True` specified for `time`, but that's not necessary. If you're submitting without setting values for `title`, `body`, or `location` the form is not valid. If that's not the problem, I'd check on what values are getting passed in for your `time` input. You've declared it as a `DateTimeField`, and if your Javascript widget isn't producing a string that the field can parse that's not valid. Are you seeing form error messages after submitting?

Comment: No, I'm not seeing any errors, even if I submit without entering any values, which is strange. I think you were right, I took out the javascript widget and it appears to be working...I'll keep working on the formatting of the datetimefield

Comment: It's not that strange - your template doesn't render errors from `show_form` except for `non_field_errors`. If you want to render each field yourself, you should render each field's `errors` attribute somewhere.

Comment: I think you were right, I took out the javascript widget and it appears to be working...I'll keep working on the formatting of the datetimefield

Comment: I haven't run into any really first-class widgets for picking both a date and a time, but I've used this jQuery add-on in the past: http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/ - I don't really like its interface, but it beats raw text. There are probably other options out there.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I'll take a look at it. This was driving me crazy.

Comment: @user2676680, next time, print errors instead of guessing why is_valid is false. You can show it in your template, print(form.errors), etc.

Answer (score 1):

If new_Show is a model, why not create a `ModelForm` instead of `forms.Form`?

So, instead of

```
class NewShowForm(forms.Form):
    title=forms.CharField()
    body=forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextArea)
    location=forms.CharField()
    time=forms.DateTimeField(required=True)
class ImageForm(forms.Form):
    imageFile = forms.FileField(required=False, label='Select an Image')
```

why not using,

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
class NewShowForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = NewShow

class ImageForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Image
```

?

Using `ModelForm` will ensure that form validation meets that of model. Moreover, it can cut off your code (especially line 6 to 11).

Answer (score 1):

It will help to add these two lines to your view before if is_valid() to see the errors it's giving:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
  img_form = ImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
  show_form = NewShowForm(request.POST)

  print(form.is_valid())
  print(form.errors)

  if show_form.is_valid():
```

You can paste the errors here and we can see what's the issue

Answer (score -1):

Since you've put 2 Django forms together under one HTML form tag, when you submit the form on the front-end you're sending an extra field through `request.POST` that your `NewShowForm` doesn't have. If you combine both forms into a single Django form, you should be able to get this to work.

Comment: That would only matter if the forms shared a field name. Django forms pull in values from the `POST` dict based on their field names and ignore anything that they don't have a field for.

Comment: Also, if this were the problem it would be better to solve it using the `prefix` form argument rather than forcing two classes together.